# Using Wrap, and Chips inside of ListView

Tags: flutter, listview, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to have a list of data that is being returned by firebase basically represented on screen as a collection of filterable tags. The problem is when using wrap inside of my list view I am still get just a horizontal list of chips.

Light Grey is what I am after, dark grey is what is being returned

```
FutureBuilder _buildSubCategories() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: cats
            .doc(widget.catId)
            .collection('sub-categories')
            .orderBy('name')
            .get(),
        builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive());
          } else {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) {
                  // DocumentSnapshot cat = snapshot.data.docs[index];
                  return Wrap(
                    children: snapshot.data.docs
                        .map((item) => ActionChip(
                              label: Text(item['name']),
                            ))
                        .toList()
                        .cast<Widget>(),
                  );
                });
          }
        });
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use list view for that. You could simply use `Wrap`. Wrap widget pushes the overflown widget to next line

Example:

```html
FutureBuilder _buildSubCategories() {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: cats
            .doc(widget.catId)
            .collection('sub-categories')
            .orderBy('name')
            .get(),
        builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive());
          } else {
            return Wrap(
                    children: snapshot.data.docs
                        .map((item) => ActionChip(
                              label: Text(item['name']),
                            ))
                        .toList()
                        .cast<Widget>(),
                  );
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: sometimes its the simplest things we overlook. thanks so much

Comment: but if those "next lines" are more than screen height you will have "overflow error" - so `SingleChildScrollView` would be helpful

Comment: @pskink yes. If there is a chance of large items, wrapping the `Wrap` with  `SingleChildScrollView` would be helpful